# Unable to Unregister UserCustomActions added at location scriptlink using CSOM

Tags: csom, custom-actions, scriptlink

Below code was used to add Custom action to site

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script>
function AddCustomActions() {
try{
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var site = clientContext.get_web();
var UserCustomActions = site.get_userCustomActions();
 newUserCustomAction = UserCustomActions.add();
newUserCustomAction.set_location('ScriptLink');
newUserCustomAction.set_scriptSrc('~SiteCollection/SiteAssets/alert.js');
newUserCustomAction.set_sequence(10);
newUserCustomAction.set_title('New Alert');
newUserCustomAction.set_description('Global Alert');
newUserCustomAction.update();
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
catch(ex)
   {
   alert('Error: ' + ex);
   }
}
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
alert('New Support files added to Site.\n\nRefresh the page.');
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
AddCustomActions()
</script>
```

I am facing the issue as i have worngly referenced url in source and my site is down giving error:

> Cannot make a cache safe URL for `http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.3.0.js`, file not found. Please verify that the file exists under the layouts directory."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could delete the specified UserCustomAction by `Sequence` property as demonstrated below:

```
function deleteCustomAction(sequenceNo,success,error) {

    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
    var site = ctx.get_web();
    var userCustomActions = site.get_userCustomActions();
    ctx.load(userCustomActions);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
           var result = userCustomActions.get_data().filter(function(a){
               if(a.get_sequence() == sequenceNo)
                  return a;
           }); 
           if(result.length > 0){
              result[0].deleteObject(); 
              ctx.executeQueryAsync(success,error);
           } 
        },error);
}
```

Usage

```
deleteCustomAction(10,
     function(actions) {
        console.log('User custom action has been deleted');
    },
    function(sender, args) {
       console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot Vadim...Your code worked for me but had to run three times to remove userCustomAction deployed wrongly...

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the custom action and add again with correct details; some sample code to do this:

```
    Web web = context.Web;

    context.Load(web, x => x.UserCustomActions);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    List<UserCustomAction> ualist = new List<UserCustomAction>();
    foreach (var ca in web.UserCustomActions)
    {
        if (ca.ScriptSrc != null && ca.ScriptSrc.Contains("alert.js"))
        {
            ualist.Add(ca);
        }
    }

    foreach (var aa in ualist)
    {
        aa.DeleteObject();
    }

    context.ExecuteQuery();
```

You can add more checks like for Title of custom action before deleting.

Comment: using csom he said...

Comment: and using csom I wrote :)

Comment: Web web = context.Web; So now we have typed variables in CSOM ? sorry I didn't know...